# form serialize in ajax post with ckeditor throws ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in our project. passing that value in ajax post  like

```
   //$form is -> $('form') jquery object     
    $("#ajaxsubmitbutton").on('click', function () {
      CKupdate();
    $.ajax({
                        type: ($form.attr('method').toLowerCase() == 'post' ? 'POST' : 'GET'),
                        url: ($form.attr('action') == 'undefined' ? window.location : $form.attr('action')),
                        data: $form.serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {
                            // Use local eval, since it will work in this context
                            callbackFunction(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            var data = "ajaxerror";
                            callbackFunction(data);
                        }
                    });
});
```

**Ckeditor update code :**

```
function CKupdate(){
        for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
      }
```

**$form.serialize having below value :**

```
"Id=0&Title=dfg&ShortText=rer&CultureCode=en-US&StartDate=3%2F12%2F2014&EndDate=3%2F26%2F2014&Text=%3Cp%3Etest3%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A"
```

controller code :

```
 public JsonResult Save(int id, string title, string shortText, string text, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, string cultureCode)
        {
       //process some operation

}
```

it throws some ajax error like **" 500 -internal server not found"**. i don't know what is the real cause for this issue

may be the problem in serializing the form. any help on this.

Comment: what does your form action look like?

Comment: form action -> Save only.path is not problem. $form  contains some html tag content also.like "<p>test</p>",i need to pass this html tagged content too,may be that causes the issue in my assumption.i am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the tags are the issue here-

Assuming Asp.net MVC here you have two options-

Decorate your model property with the [AllowHtml] method (not sure how much of a pain it would be to convert your properties to a model here)

Put the [ValidateInput(false)] tag on your controller method
You may need to add the following tag to system.web in your config as well

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

You may also run into issues if your submit isn't a post in which case you'll want to add allowget to your return value.

Not sure if this is your issue without the full error but that is where I'd start. You may want to check the response in fiddler or firebug to see if you can get more information on that exception.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i dont have any model. i just want to pass html tag content as string in ajax post. if possible ?

Comment: Thank you very much.it works now after adding ValidateInput(false) in controller action. but no need to add code in web.config ? becuase i have not added that code in web.config ,it works eventhough

Comment: In that case I'd try the validateInput tag, although I know I've had issues getting this to work in some MVC versions. If that doesn't work you may want to put together a fast model just to get the result of your form post - you don't need to change your html at all, as long as the form post variables match up it should map correctly and that will allow you to use the currently recommended approach.

Comment: Great- Glad to hear it! I wasn't sure what version you were on - I think the validation mode setting is only needed for some of the newer MVC versions.

Comment: am using MVC4 version kelly.

Comment: i think web.config change for entire application. so no need that option for me..

Comment: No Problem :) Strange - I thought this was necessary for 4.0 but I must have been mistaken. More information on the purpose of the tag: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147